# Why does setting the unused bits of a virtual address cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, pointers, linux-kernel, x86-64, memory-address

On modern x86 platforms CPUs use either 47 or 56 bit virtual addresses theoretically masking out only the individual bit sets needed to resolve indices and offsets for the page walk. However, setting the most significant bits and dereferencing the address leads to a segmentation fault.

I would assume that perhaps the CPU immediately invokes an exception when it sees the non-zero leading bits as they may indicate a corrupted address, but I've heard in a few contexts of developers using these bits as storage for other information as referenced by [the Linux kernel docs](https://docs.kernel.org/5.19/x86/x86_64/5level-paging.html).

> On x86, 5-level paging enables 56-bit userspace virtual address space. Not all user space is ready to handle wide addresses. It’s known that at least some JIT compilers use higher bits in pointers to encode their information. It collides with valid pointers with 5-level paging and leads to crashes.

I would expect this C++ code to work, but it doesn't.

```
int* x = new int;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << *x << std::endl;
x = (int*)((unsigned long)x | (1ul << 63));
std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << *x << std::endl; // This segfaults
```

Comment: OT: Remember that `new int` will not initialize the integer you create, it will have an *indeterminate* value. And using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*. And you use the value when you print it with `*x`.

Comment: As for your problem, just never use "unused" bits, *anywhere*. It was great advice when I first started programming around 40 years ago, and it still is.

Comment: `1ul` can be a 32 bit value, `1ul << 63` can be undefined behavior.

Comment: @273K: x86-64 Linux uses the x86-64 System V ABI, where `unsigned long` is `uint64_t` which is also `uintptr_t`.  So in this particular case, the shift itself is well-defined.  (The question talks about 48 or 57-bit virtual addresses, so we know they're only talking about x86-64, not 32-bit mode.)

Comment: I assume this question is irrelevant to C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes Very smart! Edited the question and claimed the statement!

Comment: @273K: Yes, this C++ compiles to the asm we'd expect, and it segfaults because the address is non-canonical: x86-64 enforces addresses being correctly sign-extended.  (Unless you enable the new feature found in some hardware that masks the high bits for you, LAM = Linear Address Masking, intended to make tagged-pointer shenanigans like this more efficient so you don't have to clear out the tag before deref.)

Comment: **CPUs use either 47 or 56 bit virtual addresses** - that's true. **theoretically masking out only the individual bit sets needed to resolve indices and offsets** - never heard about that.

Comment: Remember to convert your "packed" pointer back into a canonical pointer before dereferencing it.

Comment: *"theoretically [X happens]. However, [putting X to the test] leads to a segmentation fault."* -- Looks like a pretty solid argument that the theory is wrong. Do you have any evidence that the theory should be correct?

Comment: Agree that the code snippet is poor style and contains UB. Just trying to briefly demonstrate the type of access which is problematic. Agreed as well, that using this technique is a poor practice since it depends on details of the hardware which vary even for x86. I'm just trying to advance my understanding. "Masking" is not quite the right word. What I mean is that I would expect the connection to the table walker to be 48-57 bits wide. So, it's surprising that something upstream is checking these bits. @PeterCordes Thank you! This is exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: Yup, some older ISAs did just ignore upper bits in early CPU models, leading to incompatibility problems when architects wanted to widen the address-space.  Even though 64 bits is wide enough to probably be "enough for anybody", the architects of x86-64 foresaw that 48 bits might not be, and wanted to make it harder for software to paint future architects into a corner by having random libraries use this in some corner of every process, even ones that will later want wider pointers for other things.  Programs can still opt in to 48-bit pointers with an allocator API, potentially.